# HTML Align text center at the same line

Tags: html, css, alignment

I was trying to align my text in my `table` and I'm wondering how do this.

My code:

```html
<table class="n">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>TITLE</strong></td>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>TITLE</strong></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center">A</td>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>MESSAGE TEST</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td style="text-align:center">C</td>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>message test lasdadlong</strong></td>

</tr
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/n5eSB/)

is there anyway of edit the text so everything start at the same line ?

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you centering, if you want everything to be aligned to the left? either you should get rid of the align center, and use align left, or I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<center><table class="n">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>TITLE</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>MESSAGE TEST</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td style="text-align:center"><strong>message test lasdadlong</strong></td>
</tr></center>
```

I have edited your code as your mentioned image, Post again edited to stable table on center. Hope it works for you.

Comment: `center` is deprecated